# Files location for Spring Boot Aplication with default configurations

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My Spring Boot App based on TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

MVC Controller:

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class JspController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        return "home";
    }
}
```

The question is where temp files are located when I run my application? I stuck with problem that my changes not always are applied after rerunning app... Please help to figure out how to get the newest code version when application running.

Comment: To find out your application's physical path, use `servletContext.getRealPath("/")`. I did not understand your rest of the question. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by sending `refresh` request from [Spring Boot Actuator](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/) list.

```
POST /refresh HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

It reloads all static an non-static components of Spring Boot Application. 
To see all available actuator requests navigate to http://localhost:8080/actuator.

To do actuator available on your application you need just to add `spring-boot-starter-actuator` maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```